# "Ошибка времени выполнения", как исправить?

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net

```
 program Zadanie;
 
const
  filename = 'dat.txt';
var
  f: Text;   // Файловая переменная.
  i: integer;  // Переменная для хранения значения количества подсчитываемых элементов.
  a: real;  // Промежуточная переменная для хранения значения читаемых элементов.
  sum: real; // переменная для хранения значения произведения.
begin
  randomize;
  assign(f,filename);  //  Связывание имени файла с файловой переменной.
  Reset(f);            //  Установка режима чтения файла.
  i:= 0;               //  Установка счетной переменной в нулевое состояние.
  sum:= 0;
  while not seekeof(f) do  // Цикл для поэлементного чтения из файла.
    begin
      read(f,a);        // Чтение информации из файла.
      write(a:8:2);
      sum:= sum + a;
      inc(i);
    end;
  writeln;
  writeln('The number of extracted numbers from the file is: ', i);
  writeln('Summa numbers from a file is equal to: ', sum:0:2);
  Close(f);  // Закрытие файла.
  readln;
end.
```

Ошибка на Reset "Ошибка времени выполнения", как исправить?

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, ваш код работает. Ошибка возможна потому, что не находит файл или он занять другим процессом.

Во - вторых, раз это PascalABC.Net, то почему бы не писать в его стиле

```
const
    filename = 'dat.txt';

var
    f: Text;   // Файловая переменная.
    i: integer;  // Переменная для хранения значения количества подсчитываемых элементов.
    a: real;  // Промежуточная переменная для хранения значения читаемых элементов.
    sum: real;// переменная для хранения значения произведения.

begin
    //    Rewrite(f, filename); 
    //    f.Writeln(2);
    //    f.Writeln(7);
    //    f.Close();
    
    f := OpenRead(filename);
    
    i := 0;               //  Установка счетной переменной в нулевое состояние.
    sum := 0;
    while not f.Eof do  // Цикл для поэлементного чтения из файла.
    begin
        a := f.ReadlnReal();        // Чтение информации из файла.
        write(a:8:2);
        sum := sum + a;
        inc(i);
    end;
    f.Close();
    
    writeln;
    writeln('The number of extracted numbers from the file is: ', i);
    writeln('Summa numbers from a file is equal to: ', sum:0:2);
    readln;
end.
```